# Latex bibliography error with acm

Tags: bibliographies

I'm a recent user of Latex because I had to use it to write my MSc thesis and I don't understand what's wrong with the bibliography. I wanted the acm bibliographystyle and so a used this:

```
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{referencias}
```

The result is every field of the reference in each line like:

> [12] Bazant, Z., and Oh, B.
>   Crack band theory for fracture of concrete.
>   Materials and Structures (1983).

I wanted a continous citation. My Bibtex file shows this:

```
@article{Bazant1983,
author = {Ba\v{z}ant, Z.P. and Oh, B.H.},
journal = {Materials and Structures},
title = {{Crack band theory for fracture of concrete}},
year = {1983}
}
```

Can someone please show me how to fix the problem?

Comment: I just added some markup to your question to make it more readable. Is that what you see?

Comment: Can you please save the following Code a `anaBibtexAcm.tex` and compile? What do you see? %Code Start %\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @article{Bazant1983,
  author = {Ba\v{z}ant, Z.P. and Oh, B.H.},
  journal = {Materials and Structures},
  title = {{Crack band theory for fracture of
  concrete}},
  year = {1983}
 }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
%codeend

Comment: the acm bibliography style specifies "newblock" (so by default a newline) after author and title, if that is not what you want, are you sure you want acm style?

Comment: My guess is that you have `openbib` in the options to `\documentclass`

Comment: My guess is that you have openbib in the options to \documentclass –  egreg 3 mins ago - I did and i deleted it and now it's solved. Thank you

Comment: @egreg ^^^^ wanna answer?

Answer (score 2):

The format you get is typical of what's produced with the

```
openbib
```

option to `\documentclass`.

Remove the option.